# ASP.NET 4.0 server error - "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on 32bit Virtual Machine

Tags: asp.net-4.0, 32-bit, virtual-machine, global-asax, httpapplication

We are receiving an error that has been difficult to find a cause for.  The error message being displayed is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  I understand what it is saying, and we have found the object that is NULL, but we cannot determine why it is occurring.

The application is an ASP.NET 4.0 app. After logging in, the system checks an Application variable that is set in Session_Start().   The variable is null and causing this error (see below for full error message displayed).

We have found that this occurs only on a 32-bit virtual machine.  Here are some that we tested on:

- XP virtual - server error
- XP non-virtual - works
- 2003 32bit virtual - server error
- 2003 32bit non-virtual - works
- 2008 64bit non-virtual - works
- 2008 32bit virtual - server error
- 2008 64bit virtual - works

We tested by moving the entire project to the virtual machine and compiled it using VS 2010 Express.  The application then worked correctly.  The application then worked correctly.  Therefore, it seems that if this application is precompiled, on a 32bit virtual machine, the NullReferenceException error will appear.

Since we have proven this works on most machines, we are confident it is not the code.  What do we need to check now?  Is there something that is not installed on the virtual machines?  Any suggestions of things to look for or try would be appreciated.  If you need me to clarify something or give more information, please let me know.

> Server Error in '/TestSite'
>   Application. Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   HomeMasterPage.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +204
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr
>   fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>   +14    System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +35
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +91
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +74    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +146    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.1

**updated after comments**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        ArrayList ArrActiveUser = new ArrayList();
        Application["ArrActiveUser"] = ArrActiveUser;
    }

...


    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started
        ArrayList ActiveUsers = new ArrayList(); 
        if (Application["ArrActiveUser"] != null)
        {
            ActiveUsers = (ArrayList)Application["ArrActiveUser"];
        }
        ActiveUsers.Add(Session.SessionID);
        Application["ArrActiveUser"] = ActiveUsers;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `HomeMasterPage.Page_Load`, and point out line 204 for us?  We'd like to see it before agreeing with your conclusion that the code isn't flawed.

Comment: ...and also show us the code in `Session_Start` that initialises the app-level variable.

Comment: That is the strange thing about this error.  There is no line 204 in the HomeMasterPage.  The null object is here  ArrayList ActiveUsers = (ArrayList)Application["ArrActiveUser"];
                ActiveUsers.Remove(Session.SessionID);
                Application["ArrActiveUser"] = ActiveUsers;

Comment: @LukeH - I posted the code you requested

Comment: We have found that the events in the global.asax are possibly not firing on the virtual machines.  Any ideas why that would be occurring?

Comment: This seems to be the same error we are having, however it is on a Windows 7 Desktop PC, and it in VB code rather than C# code, but it still deals with the Application collection.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a stateserver?  Session_Start / Session_End don't ever get fired unless your session state is inProc, I believe.